# How to insert values into microsoft access database through ado code?

Tags: database, ms-access, insert, ado

I am trying to learn ADO from http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_add.asp. The asp file that includes ado code that I am using is shown below. When I try to run it off my personal computer server, I get
"No update permissions!" error. Does anyone know how to insert values into Microsoft Access database table through ado code or grant update permissions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%
    set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open "my_db"
    sql="INSERT INTO Name_t VALUES ('4', 'Jason', '5')"  
    on error resume next
    conn.Execute sql,recaffected
    if err<>0 then
        Response.Write("No update permissions!")
    else
    Response.Write("<h3>" & recaffected & " record added</h3>")
    end if
    conn.close
%> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `"No update permissions!"` error because that's the text you are returning in the error section.

Check to see what the actual error message is, coming back in the `Err` object. Like so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%
    set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open "my_db"
    sql="INSERT INTO Name_t VALUES ('4', 'Jason', '5')"  
    on error resume next
    conn.Execute sql,recaffected
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       Response.Write ("Error Updating Database: " & Err.Description & "<br><br>")
    else
      Response.Write("<h3>" & recaffected & " record added</h3>")
    end if
    conn.close
%> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I run it, I get error:

"Error Updating Database: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Operation must use an updateable query."

The problem might be permissions' settings. I tried to set permissions by clicking on the properties of the folder where db was located, and by granting permissions from "Users and permissions" part of my Microsoft Office 365 Access (also from Admin account, and made sure that all admin rights granted). The same error was  generated. How can I make code change my Microsoft Access database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to insert code from html to MS access database in Javascript.

NOTE: Only works in IE since ACTIVEXOBJECT is not defined in other browsers.
Still trying to work around it.

```
var pad = "C:\\Users\\yourpathtodb";
  var strConn = "Provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;Data Source=" + pad;
  var adoConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
  var adoRS = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

  adoConn.Open(strConn);

  adoRS.Open("Select * From tableName", adoConn, 1, 3);

  adoRS.AddNew;
  adoRS.Fields("field1").value =document.idOfInputTag.value;

  adoRS.Close();
  adoConn.Close();
```